# Which font filetype is correct to use in chrome on a PC?

Tags: css, windows, macos, google-chrome

I thought it was `.ttf` files but theres a massive disparity between how my icon fonts are rendering on a PC and a Mac.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32332055/concat/index.html

They render perfectly on Mac Chrome (Version 30.0.1599.101)

But horribly on PC Chrome (Version 30.0.1599.101 m)

Does the browser use a slightly different rendering engine between Mac and PC ? and if so what filetype renders best in Chrome on a PC.

For this project, I don't care about other browsers in the least

Comment: I strongly doubt that another file-type will help you here. There are many other factors affecting font-rendering and chrome on windows does usually not render fonts very well. It's also very often an issue of the fonts themselves not being designed very well for the different environments. Anyhow I'm looking forward to answers on this one. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome 3 supported OTF and TTF fonts, but not by default—you had to do a command-line switch to enable it.`.svg` will work in all versions of Chrome.

Check out this page on fonts: http://www.stunningcss3.com/resources/fontface-file-types-browser-support.html

Comment: `.svg`looks though it might be rendering nicer, although it may just be me having been staring at the screen for hours. +1

Comment: just loading both next to each other for comparison and if its clearer i'll provide some screenshots and accept your answer...

Comment: There was no noticeable difference in a side by side comparison, even at a much larger / smaller font size I'll stick with `.svg`for compatibility with the older versions of chrome for now